# How to change bottomSheet open/display style like default is bottom to top i want top to bottom

Tags: android

**I want to show bottom Sheet from top to bottom. Default BottomSheet Open From bottom to top but i want bottom sheet open form Title/Toolbar/ActionBar**

I Search On google but can't find solution

This is My Code

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cordinate"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.bttomsheettoptobottom.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btOpenBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Show Bottom Sheet"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btOpenBottomSheet;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;


    private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            switch (view.getId()){

                case R.id.btOpenBottomSheet:

                    showBottomSheetDialog();

                    break;
            }

        }

    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        btOpenBottomSheet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btOpenBottomSheet);
        btOpenBottomSheet.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    }

    private void showBottomSheetDialog() {


        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.cordinate);

        View bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById(R.id.llBottomSheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // React to state change
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                // React to dragging events
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom TopsheetBehaviour class as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/mohansmk23/6fc1c8441528fd9bd401a0ddf82c5d44) and make the sheet Behaviour as

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     app:layout_behavior="your.package.components.TopSheetBehavior"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

It worked in my case. Hope it helps to you!